# Passing style <p> to CKEditor Text Area

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ckeditor

Currently I am trying to pass a paragraph that contain style to CKEditor text area then edit the content. So when the html pass to the text area, the style went missing. Is there any configuration for CKEditor or any ways to do it?

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="summary-ckeditor" name="summary-ckeditor"></textarea>

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['summary-ckeditor'];
    editor.insertHtml("<div style='color: red'>Trying to get this code 
in red color when passing to CKEditor text area</div>");
```

It able to show the content but without style

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of your code.

Comment: Can you try changing the quotes - maybe the style attribute is not recognized as valid? Try this: `editor.insertHtml('<div style="color:red">....` - did this make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the CKEditor documentation [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/api.html#), you have to get the CKEditor instance (in your case) like this

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="ckeditor_Instance" name="summary-ckeditor"></textarea>
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor_Instance;
```

Then you can insert html (with font color) using the `<font>` tag, mentioned [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/colorbutton.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20add%20them,color%20selection%20drop-down%20list.)

```
var _html = '<p><font color="#FF0000">This is an inserted tag</font></p>';
editor.insertHtml(_html);
```

You can also add background color like this

```
var _html = '<p><font style="background-color:#FFFF00;">This is an inserted tag with background color.</font></p>';
editor.insertHtml(_html);
```

**Note:-** I have tried this with the CDN for full version

`<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.0/full/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Comment: Not sure why but still not working. Also I had tried to install the plugin for color code and add config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton'; but not working as well

Comment: You have to use the full version [ckeditor docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/colorbutton.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20add%20them,color%20selection%20drop-down%20list.) like i said in my answer.